# OpenCV Segmentation Fault during Feature Matching

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-detection, feature-extraction, feature-selection

This function extracts and computes the query.keypoints:

```
// extract features
analyzer->analyze(query);
```

like this:

```
bool Analyzer::analyze(Query &query) {
    // detect keypoints
    query.keypoints.clear();
    assert(query.keypoints.empty());
    detector->detect(query.grayImage, query.keypoints);

    // no keypoints detected!
    if (query.keypoints.empty()) {
        cout << "no keypoints detected!" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    // compute descriptors
    query.descriptors.release();
    assert(query.descriptors.empty());
    extractor->compute(query.grayImage, query.keypoints, query.descriptors);

    // note: keypoints for which a descriptor cannot be computed are removed
    if (query.keypoints.empty()) {
        cout << "cannot compute keypoints!" << endl;
        return false;
    }
}
```

after this i match the query.keypoints with the pattern/training keypoints:

```
// if analyze() is ok, match descriptors
analyzer->match(query);
```

Like this:

```
void Analyzer::match(Query &query) {
    assert(!query.descriptors.empty());
    // query.matches.clear();
    matcher->match(query.descriptors, query.matches);
}
```

Now i want to analyze the matching set:

```
double max_dist = 200; double min_dist = 100;

//-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
for( int i = 0; i < pattern->descriptors.rows; i++ ) { 
    double dist = query.matches[i].distance;
    if( dist < min_dist ) min_dist = dist;
    if( dist > max_dist ) max_dist = dist;
}

//-- Localize the object
std::vector<cv::Point2f> obj;
std::vector<cv::Point2f> scene;

for( int i = 0; i < pattern->descriptors.rows; i++ ) { 
    if( query.matches[i].distance <= max(2*min_dist, 0.02) ) {
        // get keypoints from good matches

        // SEGMENTATION FAULT HERE!
        // query.matches[i].queryIdx seems to be negative? possible?
        cout << query.keypoints[query.matches[i].queryIdx].pt <<endl;

        // BASICALLY THIS FAILS
        // obj.push_back( pattern->keypoints[ query.matches[i].queryIdx ].pt );
        // scene.push_back( query.keypoints[ query.matches[i].trainIdx ].pt );
    }
}
```

But each time i try, i get a Segmentation Fault in the code above on line

```
// SEGMENTATION FAULT HERE!
// query.matches[i].queryIdx seems to be negative? possible?
cout << query.keypoints[query.matches[i].queryIdx].pt <<endl;
```

i think that there are missing keypoints. so i am not able to retrieve query.keypoints by queryID.

```
cv::DMatch match = query.matches[i];
cout << match.queryIdx << endl;
cout << query.matches.size() << endl;
int queryID = match.queryIdx;
cv::KeyPoint test = query.keypoints[queryID]; // FAILS
cout << test.pt << endl;
```

What i am doing wrong?? I am stucked..! Please enlight me.. ;)

--- EDIT ---

Here is the Valgrind Memcheck output:

```
[Result] Features:  420; Matches:  181; Time(ms): 757.842
Creating Query instance..
-- Max dist : 224,000000 
-- Min dist : 0,000000 
==11770== Invalid read of size 4
==11770==    at 0x41759C: cv::Point_<float>::Point_(cv::Point_<float> const&) (operations.hpp:1623)
==11770==    by 0x41A166: cv::KeyPoint::KeyPoint(cv::KeyPoint const&) (features2d.hpp:69)
==11770==    by 0x41AFA2: Controller::detectObject(om::Query&) (Controller.cpp:169)
==11770==    by 0x41B9B7: Controller::displayFunction(cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&) (Controller.cpp:261)
==11770==    by 0x414909: processVideo() (App.cpp:109)
==11770==    by 0x414C4F: main (App.cpp:144)
==11770==  Address 0x2c9d9620 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==11770== 
==11770== 
==11770== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==11770==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x2C9D9620
==11770==    at 0x41759C: cv::Point_<float>::Point_(cv::Point_<float> const&) (operations.hpp:1623)
==11770==    by 0x41A166: cv::KeyPoint::KeyPoint(cv::KeyPoint const&) (features2d.hpp:69)
==11770==    by 0x41AFA2: Controller::detectObject(om::Query&) (Controller.cpp:169)
==11770==    by 0x41B9B7: Controller::displayFunction(cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&) (Controller.cpp:261)
==11770==    by 0x414909: processVideo() (App.cpp:109)
==11770==    by 0x414C4F: main (App.cpp:144)
==11770==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==11770==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==11770==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==11770==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==11770==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==11770== 
==11770== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11770==     in use at exit: 37,488,211 bytes in 27,473 blocks
==11770==   total heap usage: 121,456 allocs, 93,983 frees, 60,575,106 bytes allocated
==11770== 
==11770== LEAK SUMMARY:
==11770==    definitely lost: 16,496 bytes in 35 blocks
==11770==    indirectly lost: 2,140,260 bytes in 623 blocks
==11770==      possibly lost: 22,477,384 bytes in 1,566 blocks
==11770==    still reachable: 12,635,159 bytes in 24,368 blocks
==11770==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11770== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==11770== 
==11770== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==11770== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==11770== ERROR SUMMARY: 1502 errors from 47 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Killed
```

with --leak-check=full

```
==11938== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==11938==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x2C774CA4
==11938==    at 0x41759C: cv::Point_<float>::Point_(cv::Point_<float> const&) (operations.hpp:1623)
==11938==    by 0x41A166: cv::KeyPoint::KeyPoint(cv::KeyPoint const&) (features2d.hpp:69)
==11938==    by 0x41AFA2: Controller::detectObject(om::Query&) (Controller.cpp:169)
==11938==    by 0x41B9B7: Controller::displayFunction(cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&) (Controller.cpp:261)
==11938==    by 0x414909: processVideo() (App.cpp:109)
==11938==    by 0x414C4F: main (App.cpp:144)
==11938==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==11938==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==11938==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==11938==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==11938==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==11938== 
==11938== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11938==     in use at exit: 35,574,636 bytes in 27,138 blocks
==11938==   total heap usage: 97,784 allocs, 70,646 frees, 58,484,719 bytes allocated
```

Comment: At what line you get the segfault? Have you tried some tool like valgrind?

Comment: please print query.matches[i].queryIdx and query.matches.size and query.keypoints.size before segfault !

Comment: done. it seems that there is no query.keypoints[queryID]; - but why??

Comment: shouldnt become negative I guess...

Comment: can you change thr loop to run over matches.size()???

Comment: i mean to change `for( int i = 0; i < pattern->descriptors.rows; i++ ) { ` to `for( int i = 0; i < query.matches.size(); i++ ) { ` because maybe you went out of the matches range (maybe not every keypoint got a sufficiently good match!

Comment: Well, sorry for being so late.. but you are right! Thank you! :)